# Highcharts: generate PDF document from export.highcharts.com without showing trace

Tags: highcharts

I think I am missing something.

I have a simple column chart. I have the following in the chart configuration:

```
exporting: {
    enabled: false
},
```

On the chart, there is a little dropdown allowing me to download the chart as PDF. When I did that in Firefox, there is a popup window showing the name of the PDF file and export from http://export.highcharts.com

I have Firebug in my Firefox and I am unable to see any remote call in the Firebug console to export.highcharts.com. Why am I unable to see any remote call trace? I know I must miss something and thanks for letting me know what it is.

Regards.

Comment: Give it a try in chrome, I can see the POST request in the NETWORK tab in the default firefox tools, I do not have firebug installed.

Comment: Jugal, thanks for your info. I saw that in Chrome. After you pointing to the Network tab, I checked the Net tab in FF, it shows the remote call too. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, let's close it with an answer than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) on firebug for the remote calls. Double check that the net panel is enabled in the [options menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Options_Menu)